# Appending a list of lists and adding a column efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Appending works fine with this method:

```
for poss in pos:
    df = df.append([[poss,'1']], ignore_index=True)
```

Is this possible to write as a one-liner? This way is showing a syntax error.

```
df = df.append([[poss,'1']], ignore_index=True) for poss in pos
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. It seems like you are looking to use list comprehension syntax to single-linify multiple method calls. You can't do this.

Instead, what you can do is aggregate your list elements into a dataframe and append in one go. It is also inefficient to `df.append` within a loop versus building a dataframe from list of lists and appending just once.

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(pos, columns=player_df.columns))
```

This assumes `pos` is a list of lists with columns aligned with `df`.

If you need to add an extra column "in one line", try this:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(pos, columns=player_df.columns)).assign(newcol=1)
```

Comment: I want  two columns.pos column contains some data another column contains value '1'.How to do this in one go

Comment: Add the 1 column later. No need to build a list with repeated items. Doing it "in one go" is inefficient.

Comment: @Anesh, also added a solution to satisfy your "1-line" criterion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, but I cannot test it, because I do not work with those datatypes and normal `list.append` does not return the resulting list.

```
from functools import reduce # Python3 only

df = reduce(lambda d, p: d.append([[p,'1']], ignore_index=True), pos, df)
```

Anyway, the for loop is much better. Also this is just a rewrite to one line. There might be other ways to modify your data.